# File was not uploaded Magento 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images, image-upload, upload

Cant upload any images to new or existing products. Updated magento to 1.9.3.10 but it didn't fix the issue. Looked at different solution but so far can't fix it. Tried permissions, cache. All unsuccessfully

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the error, it is giving a max resolution issue, try uploading a smaller image. Also check for the directory for **write** permission.

Comment: have 755 on media folder, where can i check the errors? even files that were fine before won't upload.

Comment: check errors in `var/log` folder.

Comment: @Y.Chugai by default the log would not be enabled, you can check that in the admin panel -> System->configuration->Developer->Log,

Comment: 2018-10-14T21:19:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _collectionSize  in /home/becrnbvk/public_html/shop/app/design/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-002/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 129

Answer (score 0):

image upload works perfectly on clean install. replaced media folders from old install to clean one and still able to upload images. so permissions are fine then.

Answer (score 0):

[image: x]

even the wording in table looks strange. there is definitely something broken but i can not find what and where